# Using Probability for n-gram string queries

Tags: probability-or-statistics, string-manipulation

I want to use Probability to ask questions on strings like "what's the probability of the occurrence of the trigram 'the' conditioned on the occurence of the digram 'th'?"

This doesn't work. I believe that I'm misusing the predicates, should x and y belong to the same EmpiricalDistribution?

```
gettys = ExampleData[{"Text", "GettysburgAddress"}]
Probability[
 x == {"t", "h", "e"} \[Conditioned] y == {"t", "h"},
 {x \[Distributed] 
  EmpiricalDistribution[Partition[Characters@gettys, 3, 1]], 
  y \[Distributed] EmpiricalDistribution[Partition[Characters@gettys, 2, 1]]} ]
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't use non-numeric data for `EmpiricalDistribution` (at least up to V9, and I saw nothing when I had 10.x installed that said otherwise).

Deal with it as character codes:

```
gc = ToCharacterCode@ToLowerCase@gettys;
p3 = Partition[gc, 3, 1];
d = EmpiricalDistribution@p3;
Probability[{a, b, c} == 
   ToCharacterCode@"the" \[Conditioned] {a, b} == 
   ToCharacterCode@"th", {a, b, c} \[Distributed] d]

(* 21/44 *)
```

You can also use `WeightedData` to arrive at the same end, with a side-benefit of having properties that can be queried directly:

```
wd = WeightedData @@ Transpose@Tally[p3];
d2 = EmpiricalDistribution@wd;
Probability[{a, b, c} == 
   ToCharacterCode@"fou" \[Conditioned] {a, b} == 
   ToCharacterCode@"fo", {a, b, c} \[Distributed] d2]

(* 1/5 *)
```

Arguably, just using string functions is cleaner, and likely faster (you'll probaby want to define a stricter pattern than here, or use positions, to ensure results are from overlaps):

```
With[{t = ToLowerCase@gettys}, StringCount[t, {"the"}]/StringCount[t, {"th"}]]

(* 21/44 *)
```